# Retrieve all strings in a webpage in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve all strings from a webpage using BeautifulSoup and return a list of all the retrieved strings.

I have 2 approaches in mind:

1. Find all elements who have a text that is not null, append the text to result list and return it. I am having a hard time implementing this as I couldn't find any way to do it in BeautifulSoup.
2. Use BeautifulSoup's "find_all" method to find all attributes that I am looking for such as "p" for paragraphs, "a" for links etc. The problem I am facing with this approach is that for some reason, find_all is returning a duplicated output. For example, if a website has a link with a text "Get Hired", I am receiving "Get Hired" more than once in the output.

I am honestly not sure how to proceed from here and I have been stuck for several hours trying to figure out how to get all strings form a webpage.

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use `.stripped_strings` to get all the strings with whitespaces stripped off.**

> `.stripped_strings` - Read the [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#strings-and-stripped-strings).

Here is the code that returns a `list` of strings present inside the `<body>` tag.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'YOUR URL GOES HERE...'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

b = soup.find('body')
list_of_strings = [s for s in b.stripped_strings]
```

`list_of_strings` will have a list of all the strings present in the URL.

Comment: This works beautifully. I am still facing the issue of the nav bar being outputted more than once but I think this is related to the website that I am scraping. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Post the code that you've used.

If I remember correctly, something like this should get the complete page in one variable "page" and all the text of the page would be available as page.text

```
import requests

URL = "https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/"
page = requests.get(URL)

print(page.text)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, print(page.text) is also duplicating the elements in the nav bar 3 times

Comment: What does the "page source" look like when you check it in a browser?

Comment: You can try something like this to remove duplicates - even if they are in the html source.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-handle-duplicate-attributes-in-beautifulsoup/

Comment: I iterated over BeautifulSoup's soup.body.strings to get all text in the webpage and then I split the text on space and manipulated strings to clean them. I am not sure if you're familiar with the "strings" method but it worked. However, the count of some scraped strings that I got does not match that on the website when I control + F to search for that same string.

Comment: Weird.  I'm out of ideas.